# Word Interop - How to determine if a word doc has page number in Header/footer

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I want to know if a Word Document has page number in the Header/Footer using Interop.Word in C#.

I have gone this far

```
try
{
    foreach (Section SectionObj in DocObj.Sections)
    {          
        foreach (HeaderFooter HeaderObj in SectionObj.Footers)
        {
            if (HeaderObj.Exists && (HeaderObj.Shapes.Count > 0 || !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(HeaderObj.Range.Text) || HeaderObj.Range.Text.Equals("\r"))))
            {
                if(HeaderObj.PageNumbers.NumberStyle == WdPageNumberStyle.wdPageNumberStyleNumberInDash 
                || HeaderObj.PageNumbers.NumberStyle == WdPageNumberStyle.wdPageNumberStyleUppercaseLetter 
                || HeaderObj.PageNumbers.NumberStyle == WdPageNumberStyle.wdPageNumberStyleUppercaseRoman 
                || HeaderObj.PageNumbers.NumberStyle == WdPageNumberStyle.wdPageNumberStyleNumberInCircle 
                || HeaderObj.PageNumbers.NumberStyle == WdPageNumberStyle.wdPageNumberStyleLowercaseRoman 
                || HeaderObj.PageNumbers.NumberStyle == WdPageNumberStyle.wdPageNumberStyleLowercaseLetter 
                || HeaderObj.PageNumbers.NumberStyle == WdPageNumberStyle.wdPageNumberStyleHindiLetter1)
                {
                    PageNumber = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e) { }
```

But the checks cannot determine if it is Page number or not. What should I do to determine if it has page numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the Header and the Footer of Section using the PageNumbers.Count propertie.

```
    private bool HeaderOrFooterHasPageNumber(Word.HeaderFooter headOrFooter)
    {
        if (headOrFooter != null)
            return headOrFooter.PageNumbers.Count > 0;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

And you can call this like...

```
        bool hasNumberPages = false;

        Word.Document doc = WordApp.ActiveDocument;
        try
        {
            Word.HeaderFooter headOrFooter = null;
            Word.Section section = null;

            for (int i = 1; i <= doc.Sections.Count; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    section = doc.Sections[i];
                    if(section != null)
                    {
                        headOrFooter = section.Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];
                        hasNumberPages = HeaderOrFooterHasPageNumber(headOrFooter);
                        if (hasNumberPages)
                            break;

                        headOrFooter = section.Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterEvenPages];
                        hasNumberPages = HeaderOrFooterHasPageNumber(headOrFooter);
                        if (hasNumberPages)
                            break;

                        headOrFooter = section.Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage];
                        hasNumberPages = HeaderOrFooterHasPageNumber(headOrFooter);
                        if (hasNumberPages)
                            break;

                        headOrFooter = section.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];
                        hasNumberPages = HeaderOrFooterHasPageNumber(headOrFooter);
                        if (hasNumberPages)
                            break;

                        headOrFooter = section.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterEvenPages];
                        hasNumberPages = HeaderOrFooterHasPageNumber(headOrFooter);
                        if (hasNumberPages)
                            break;

                        headOrFooter = section.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage];
                        hasNumberPages = HeaderOrFooterHasPageNumber(headOrFooter);
                        if (hasNumberPages)
                            break;
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    if(headOrFooter != null)
                    {
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(headOrFooter);
                        headOrFooter = null;
                    }

                    if (section != null)
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(section);
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (doc != null)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any resource where I can learn more of MS Office document properties?

Comment: This page is like base reference [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn320432.aspx), but in google you can find a lot of documentatios and examples. Here in StackOverflow you will find a lot of questions, but in Code Project [link](https://www.codeproject.com/) and specially in Addin express forum [link](https://www.add-in-express.com/forum/) you will find a lot about it. @naqushab